# Django Debug Toolbar text garbled

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I recently upgraded my Python packages to the latest versions. One of the ones I upgraded was Django Debug Toolbar for my Django website development. Now every page has garbled text all over it:

[image: Text on each page]

What can I do to fix this? I know it's Django Debug Toolbar causing it because when I remove it from the settings.py file everything renders correctly.

Comment: Just ran into this problem myself. Something tells me it's the newer version of the toolbar. I can also see a JS error for toolbar.js: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Not sure if they're related though.